# Why is the ArC extension marked as unlisted on the extensions page?

Tags: quarkus

ArC is one of the Core extensions of Quarkus. And yet, when searching for it on [the extensions page of quarkus.io](https://quarkus.io/extensions/) it does not appear in the results. In contrast, other core extensions like `agroal` and `avro` do appear. Why is that?

When you type out its name in the search field, it does appear, but it is tagged as 'Unlisted'. I've looked for a reason in the https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus repo, in the forum and here on StackOverflow, but have not a single explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Quarkus extensions are so core that they're actually more foundational. Almost every other Quarkus extension depends directly or indirectly on ArC, so there's usually no need for a user to add it directly to a `pom.xml` or select it from the list on http://code.quarkus.io.

Because users don't need to do anything with it, the extension is unlisted, and doesn't show on http://code.quarkus.io or http://extensions.quarkus.io. However, as you've observed, if a user *really* wants to find out information about the ArC extension, they can search for it directly on http://extensions.quarkus.io and information will be shown.

The existence of unlisted extensions isn't documented, because the reason to not show them is to streamline and reduce clutter, and having lots of documentation about the information that isn't being shown would undo that, and end up being *more* clutter. However, if this is something that will trip people up, a 'what does this mean' tooltip might be helpful.